# Font hosted in Google drive

Tags: css, fonts, google-drive-api, cors

I host a personal Font on Google drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVD73plILCg3HMZtlciMPMaJac-z6KDT/view?usp=sharing as an open source for anyone). 
I try to use it as I would do for a photo or video, but in css. 
In the code i have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'harry_pregular';
    src: url('https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1DVD73plILCg3HMZtlciMPMaJac-z6KDT&export=download') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It does not change and give back :

> Access to font at 'https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1YnKrdJVpKxK4DATN6zEUNLkC58ueoLRS&export=download'
> from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

referring the font file i set to download.

I don't understand. (I'm using my local computer) so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"so what am I doing wrong?"_ - well, you are trying to misuse Google Drive as a sort of CDN for your website - but it wasn't meant for that in the first place.

Comment: Common browsers will only use webfonts, if they are served with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, explicitly _allowing_ their usage on the target website. This was implemented, because commercial fonts are often only licensed to be used on specific sites.

Comment: ok. I so out of the folders i can not use fonts? @CBroe

Comment: No, you can't, because you won't be able to make Google Drive serve the file with the necessary header. And you _shouldn't_ to begin with (even for other resources, that such restrictions don't apply to, such as f.e. images) - Google Drive is _not meant_ to be a CDN for your website.

Comment: Google drive is NOT a file hosting service.   @CBroe why dont you write all that up in an answer explain why this is not going to work.  or better yet why it shouldnt work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

As @CBroe and @DaImTo said in the comments, Google Drive is [not a file hosting service](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html). This applies to hosting a personal font in Google Drive, for this you need hosting support in order to correctly serve a font-file.

Comment: The comments and this answer makes the assumption that the OP is misusing Drive and/or the font licensing terms.  However, this isn't necessarily the case?  For example, if the use case is for a student studying web programming and building a sample page for coursework assignments?  Furthermore, I think whether or not Google Drive is *capable* of serving the font files, as opposed to whether or not they *should* serve them, are entirely separate issues altogether; afterall, if the licensing *does* allows for it, then wouldn't that distinction become moot?