# How can I use Google Drive to host a ttf file for my code?

Tags: html, fonts, google-drive-api, truetype, google-sites

This is my code:

```html
<style>
  @font-face { 
  font-family: WinterSong; 
  src: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/13bQUuIO2hSWG1W00lxTZnCkI7Iml2mx2/view?usp=sharing'); 
} 


#WinterSong {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
</style>

<div id="WinterSong">text</div>
```

but it won't load the font. I want to make something with it on my school computer, so if it were possible I would use dropbox or catbox, but those are blocked. I saw a post saying I could put it in a directory in Google sites, but I haven't even come close to figuring that out. I just need to find out if it's possible to use Google to host (I'm not sure if that's the right word, I'm new to all of this) this file, and if so, how do I do that?

I was hoping it would work with https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=13bQUuIO2hSWG1W00lxTZnCkI7Iml2mx2&export=download (the link that appears when downloading it), but that didn't work either.

I tried making a Google site too, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get the format into https://sites.google.com/site/yoursitename/fonts/fontname.ttf (from an answer from [Using Custom Font Uploaded from Google Public Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044159/using-custom-font-uploaded-from-google-public-folder) which was from 2015 and the poster hasn't been on the site in years)

Comment: I don't think you can. If you could, google would be akin to a free CDN which they definitely don't want to do for every file. You should just download it on that computer and then include it locally in your code...

Comment: The main purpose of google sites is to provide a very simplistic thus restrictive framework to publish sites  without any HTML/CSS/JS knowledge. If you need to fiddle with custom code and yet don't want to invest in monthly hosting fees you should compare other free options. You could e.g create a [github page.](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart) Admittedly, not the most convenient way – it can be overwhelming – but well documented. ... since the repository would be public you shouldn't share "questionable content" =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible-

Google drive does not *host* files, it *stores* them.

See this:
[Font hosted in Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359543/font-hosted-in-google-drive)

Comment: Please don't answer questions with a link to an answer to an identical question. When you get enough rep, you'll be able to flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok- what should I do if I see a duplicate until then? I couldn't comment either.

Comment: Nothing, until you have enough rep.

Comment: Oh OK. Sorry, I didn't mean to so something wrong.